# Using series inside indexes of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have dataframe which consists of five columns and five rows:

```
Pasquil_gifford_stability_table =pd.DataFrame( {"1":['A','B','B','C','C'],
                                   "2":['A','B','C','D','D'],
                                   "3":['B','C','C','D','D'],
                                   "4":['D','E','D','D','D'],
                                   "5":['D','F','E','D','D']
                                   })
```

when  I want to take element from second column and second row,  I realise it:

```
Pasquil_gifford_stability_table.loc[2][2]
'C'
```

when  I want to take element from second third and firs row,  I also realise it:

```
Pasquil_gifford_stability_table.loc[1][3]
'E'
```

When I try to do it in arrays, I get an error:

```
    Pasquil_gifford_stability_table.loc[[2,2]],[[1,3]]
    (   1  2  3  4  5
2  B  C  C  D  E
2  B  C  C  D  E, [[1, 3]])
```

But As the result I should get

```
['C','E']
```

How should I solve that problem?

Comment: try that  Pasquil_gifford_stability_table.loc[  [2,2]  , [1,3]  ]

Comment: I tryied and got (   1  2  3  4  5
2  B  C  C  D  E
2  B  C  C  D  E, [[1, 3]])

Answer (score 0):

You want `lookup`:

```
df.lookup([2, 2], [1, 3])
```

Comment: I tried Pasquil_gifford_stability_table.lookup([2, 2], [1, 3]). As the result -  KeyError: 'One or more column labels was not found'

Comment: `df.lookup([2, 2], ['1', '3'])`?